# Adding months to a DateTime variable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datetime variable with value 12-02-2019 (12th Feb 2019) - this is what i want. But in my code, it is in MM-dd-yyyy format. It saves to db in MM-dd-yyyy format (2nd Dec 2019). When i return it from Datebase, it will be like 02-12-2019 (2nd Dec 2019).

```
  int salesid = (int)dr["SalesID"]; // dr is the datarow
  DateTime salesdate = (DateTime)dr["SalesDate"]; // 02-12-2019 (2nd Dec)
```

And I want to add 4 months to 12-02-2019 (12th Feb). But the runtime adds 4 months to 02-12-2019 (2nd dec) and i am getting 02-04-2020 !!!

```
  DateTime servicedate = salesdate.AddMonths(4); // 2020-12-02
```

This is wrong. I want to specify the salesdate as 12th Feb 2019 and ii should get 12th June 2019 after adding 4 months to the salesdate.

How this is possible in c# ?

Comment: For the value before you put into the database, is the `.Month` and `.Day` properties what you'd expect? Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Can you post your INSERT statement?  From what you're describing it sounds like your INSERT is not correct.

Comment: @JoeSewell I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a current date of 12th Feb 2019 and when i add 4 months to it, i should get 12th June 2019.

Comment: @FrankBall here is my insert query INSERT INTO tbl_Sales VALUES (" + CurrentSaleItem.CustomerID + ",'" + CurrentSaleItem.SerialNo + "','" + CurrentSaleItem.ModelNo + "','" + CurrentSaleItem.SaleDate.ToString() + "');

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Fix that.  Dates should not be strings in a database.

Comment: @Kuttan, Format your date string to mm/dd/yyyy.  SQL seems to prefer that format and using it makes sure that you get the right fields in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

When you save to the DB, make sure you are specify a more verbose format that the DB cannot confuse. For example, if you supply write to the database with `myDateTime.Format("dd MMM yyyy");` then it will not confuse the months and days around.

This will make sure that the format in your code, and in you database, all stay aligned.

Comment: Are you proposing saving the date as a string to the database?  Where does this Format function come from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your INSERT statement. While you should be passing the `DateTime` as-is to your database API, instead of using `string`s, if you want a simple fix, instead of calling [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString) on your `CurrentSaleItem.SaleDate`, use a different overload that lets you specify the culture and/or format explicitly, like [`ToString(string, IFormatProvider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)